# Can we display region label from Layouts?

Tags: theming, 8

We have a MYTHEME.layouts.yml file which defines regions...

```
layout
  label: 'Layout Name'
  path: templates/panels
  template: layout-template
  default_region: theregion
  regions:
    theregion:
      label: 'This is The Region'
```

In the template we display fields added to the region with

```
{{ content.theregion }}
```

Can we display the label that we defined?

Answer (score 1):

The labels are for administration purposes and should not be used in templates as they are hard coded and can't be changed in the UI. A better option would likely be to use a Text field where you want to display the label as that can easily be changed.

That said, you can output the region name in the twig template like this:

```
{{ layout.regions.theregion.label }}
```

Comment: Thanks!  We prefer to have the labels be not easily changed.